# "cost extra 50 dollars" or "cost an extra 50 dollars"?

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Tell me please I need to use the indefinite article in the following sentence.

> That phone costs 200 dollars, and that one will cost you (**an**) extra 50 dollars.

I think because of the adjective *extra* I need to use the article, but I am not sure. If it is really needed then why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The **indefinite article** is used because $50 ***from somewhere*** is needed.
If the $50 dollars was specific, you would use "***the***"

> That phone costs $200, and that one will cost you **an** extra $50.
>   You should pay for it with **the** $50 you have in your savings account.

The second sentence also implies you only have $50 in your savings account.

> You should pay for **the** extra $50 from your savings account.

Refers to the specific "***extra $50***".

Comment: I think the OP's query might be also about an indefinite article + the plural form of a noun - **an** extra 50 dollar**s**. If it is, then [this may be of help](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/252173/indefinite-articles-used-with-plural-nouns-it-was-an-amazing-two-days)

Comment: @MvLog +1 Good point and my use of "***$50***" needs no explaination.

Answer (score 5):

Something can **cost you**.

Something can **cost (you) extra**. <sup>extra = more</sup>

Something can **cost (you) twenty dollars|pounds extra.** <sup>extra = more</sup>

Something can **cost (you) an extra <sup>extra = additional</sup> twenty dollars|pounds.**